# SQL query a new thread in vBulletin

Tags: sql, mysql, vbulletin

How to make a query to the database(mysql) to create a thread?
I need to create a thread from a non-registered user, if not, then from the present ..
Simply query the database with the subject "Test", the text "test text" and any nickname
Sorry for bad english, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the vBulletin code-base, I'd use their datamanagers.  Otherwise, it gets very messy as there is lots of other data to update after posting.  At its very core, you'd want to insert data into the post table, and the thread table.  I'd recommend looking at the structure of those tables and going from there.